# ExtJS5 How to let keymap call viewController function?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs5

**I was wondering how to call a controller function from a keymaps in extjs 5?**

The following code in the view is working to bind the keys to a an anonymous function, however not to a controller function. The function is also called by the button, and is working. How do I set the scope correctly that it is calling the controller function?

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.users.List",{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.usersList',
    controller: 'users-list',
    listeners: {
        scope: 'controller',
        afterrender: function(window, options) {
            this.keyNav = new Ext.util.KeyMap ({
                target:window.el,
                binding: [
                    {key:"s", ctrl:true, fn: function(){alert("hallo shortkey");}},
                    {key:"c", ctrl:true, fn: "newUserFn"},
                ],
                scope:'controller'
            });
        }
    },
    tbar: [
        {
            itemId: 'users-list-btn-new',
            iconCls: 'icon-add',
            text: 'New User',
            handler: 'newUserFn'
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar troubles with scope on key press events. I'm not using a KeyMap as you are but the event logic is still relevant.

The following assumes a controller with method "saveNewComponent" that you want to call. You must fire the view event "callSave" which is being listened to in the view to correctly forward to the controller.

```
Ext.define('teams.view.component.FormPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    controller: "FormPanelController",
    listeners: {
        callSave: "saveNewComponent"
    },
    beforeShow: function(){     
        var me = this;
        me.body.dom.addEventListener("keydown", Ext.bind(onKeyDown, this), false);
        function onKeyDown(e) {
            //Listen for Ctrl+S
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.which === 83){
                e.preventDefault(); 
                me.fireEvent("callSave");
                return false;
            }
        }
    },
    ....
}
```

I tried many ways of achieving this, this this solution was the only one that had the correct context when actually inside the controller (ie **this** var was correct)